# Why does an interstellar civilisation use outdated weapons?

Tags: science-based, warfare, technological-development, interstellar

### Backstory

In a distant galaxy, humanity once had an empire sprawling hundreds of thousands of stars. Then it collapsed. Now humanity is beginning to spread again, absorbing its old colonies into a new human empire. This one is much smaller,with only a couple hundred systems at the moment. Some former colonies are quite advanced, having grown to interplanetary sizes. Others are barely in the industrial revolution. Each time, they either join willingly, or the empire manages to conquer them. Until they stumble upon the star called Agoria.

**TL;DR** why does my interstellar civilization fight against a much more advanced one (on the ground) with only modern-day weapons?

### The Agorians

The Agorians (a former human colony) are a relatively advanced society (as compared to most other former colonies), with one bit being compact fusion reactors. The smallest of them can fit in about a cubic meter or two. Most of the rest of their technology is comparable to modern-day Earth. The furthest they have gone in space is a few space stations and some people sent to the nearest planet.

However, there is one major difference: the Agorians have discovered magnetic monopoles, and combining that with fusion allowed them to develop magnetic plasma confinement (think Star Wars). This led to plasma shields, which vaporizes most matter before it can pass through the shield. As a result, for warfare, they have mostly abandoned guns and fight either with explosives (missiles) or <s>lightsabers</s> swords with a magnetically confined plasma blade. Most vehicles and infantry have some sort of plasma shielding on them. There are also larger magnetic shields, which are literally just a large magnetic field. These are less effective, but can slow or stop certain projectiles.

Their tanks fire plasma bolts, rather larger and slower then the ones in Star Wars, which do not burn, but when they encounter a surface, the confinement breaks. Due to the extreme rarefaction of the plasma, the bolt implodes, and the resulting shockwave is what causes the damage. Their bombers are literally just flying tanks that shoot at the ground.

### The Battle

Now when the humans land, for some reason, they use modern or near-future weaponry. Think tanks, modern jets, gun-wielding infantry, drones, maybe some laser AA defenses. Add to that mix short and medium range missiles, perhaps a few nukes. Due to reasons™, they cannot use orbital bombardment. Besides, they have learned some lessons from the Old Galactic Empire and are not as ruthless. On their spaceships, they have particle beams, pulsed lasers, railguns, even antimatter cannons on the larger ones. As well, they have primitive dipole shielding. Yet, they do not use these weapons on the surface. Why don't they mount a particle beam or a railgun on a tank against the Agorians? Why do they use outdated weaponry on the surface?

Comment: Asteroids dropped upon a planet don't need to travel at relativistic speeds. You haven't actually established why a vast and powerful civilization actually cares about subjugation. Honestly, it feels like you could rewrite your scenario to avoid all of the super-ultra-tech, and not need to think up clumsy excuses as to why it isn't used, because it didn't have to exist in the first place. Fantastic arms control always seemed like a lazy writing excuse to me.

Comment: @StarfishPrime honestly, I don't see how I *could* rewrite it for the weaker to defeat the stronger. As for subjugation, why do modern superpowers care about it? Why don't we just nuke everything?

Comment: @StarfishPrime as for powerful weaponry, *both* sides have it, but one side does not use it. That is the question.

Comment: Why do they have these weapons then, when the story requires them to not use them? Wouldn't it make more sense for them to simply not have them?

Comment: @Cadence because an interstellar civilization would obviously have such weapons. This is just one plot of many in my universe, and it would kinda be suspicious if they are absent from other (space) battles.

Comment: Thing is, a galaxy spanning civilization that has absorbed K2-level colonies is nearly incomprehensively vast and complex. It must necessarily be hugely more socially, scientifically and technologically advanced than us for such a civilization to be a cohesive hole. This is all part of the [Scifi writers have no sense of scale](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ScifiWritersHaveNoSenseOfScale) trope... you've created a galaxy of superhumans! If you didn't want superhuman powers involved, _scale it back_.

Comment: But as your your question "_why don't superpowers nuke everything?_" surely you can just look at the real world and [MAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_assured_destruction) and its fictional cousins in things like the Dune universe. The real world has plenty of examples of weak defeating "strong", eg. Algeria, Afghanistan, Vietnam, but the power levels involved are many orders of magnitude less because neither side is necessarily strongly superhuman.

Comment: @StarfishPrime i guess ure right about having me having no sense of scale. note though, that it's only the *former* human empire that was galaxy spanning, this one is still expanding (a few hundred systems at most). i gurss i also overlooked MAD. i was thinking more of "keeping the people alive and the infrastructure mostly intact"

Comment: I guess this question no longer applies then, should i delete it?

Comment: @Seggan its up to you. You could rewrite it to focus on a smaller subset of the issues or technology. If you wait a bit, you might even get an answer on your original question that you like! I'm not the boss here ;-) You just had the misfortune to touch upon two of my pet peeves simultaneously, fantastic arms control and kardashev scale underestimation.

Comment: Honestly? Just go and read Dune again, he already did all this already didn't he (energy shields that make projectile weapons impractical and all that jazz) .. and anyway, why wouldn't they use the same 'outdated' kit that's been working so well for them in all their other conquests, they don't know what's down there or that it negates most of their normal weapons do they, they only just got here .. so where's your problem here, because I just don't see it.

Comment: @Pelinore hmm, interesting. i havent thought of that

Comment: VTC. The [help/on-topic] states, "When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story." It'd be possible to create a rule for a single world (e.g., radiation interferes with high tech…), but a global condition is simply a story rationalization (…an elegant weapon from a more civilized age). Any answer is no more valuable than, "they do because they can" (see [help/dont-ask]). Frankly, it's hard to justify any invasion solution not chemical bombardment. Kill the sapient species, wait for it to go inert, then settle. No partisans.

Answer (score 4):

**Their society was never pushed to improve their ground forces**

Giving the most advanced weapons to the infantry would require a strong push toward the miniaturization. The idea of investing money and energies in these fields would be seen as a useless waste of resources.

So far, the empire have been able to conquer planets by the sheer power of its ships: defeating the enemy fleet in the space and conquering the planetary orbit was enough to force the enemy planets to surrender.
For the empire, ground forces and their equipment were little more than an afterthought, since a serious engagement on the surface never happened.

Updating the weapons would require years of research, without thinking about the supply, but they cannot wait for it (maybe the generals cannot waste too much time to avoid the wrath of the emperor...)

So, against the Algorians, since they cannot exploit the control of the orbit, they found themselves in the need to fight on the surface with the weapons at their disposals, which were never updated.

Answer (score 3):

**The Human Empire has run short of Illudium Phosdex**

Amazing new technology requires vast quantities of both [Unobtanium](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Unobtainium) and [Illudium Phosdex](https://youtu.be/ukTuKnIZCUU) (the shaving cream atom). Humans have run short of these critical minerals while the Agorians have mountains of the stuff.

**The Human Empire have too many slaves and need to lose a few billion**

To supply their vast engine of [conquernation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forever_War), humanity has resorted to the ancient practice of demanding [slave warriors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghilman) from newly conquered worlds. Worlds refusing to supply slave-troops would routinely have their [above age-6 male populations totally eliminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measuring_against_the_linchpin). To prevent the slaves from rebelling, they are only supplied weapons of 20th Century Earth while the rulers of *Human! Space!™* have plenty of fantastic weapons that would easily prevent slave uprisings. Slave warriors of the [Mamluk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamluk) class (sometimes called Orks due to common reactions to the drugs issued) were supplied with [Polydichloric Euthimal](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/Outland) which tends to limit their lifespan to at most 2 wars. Slave warriors of the [Janissary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janissary) class were supplied with better weapons, better training and tended to live much longer.

Comment: I like the idea, but that just begs the idea why they haven't stolen and used the Agorian's supply.  The answer to that may be as simple as they have stolen it, but their interstellar ships lack the proper refinery capabilities to build proper weapons with the supply without heading to another planet and/or it just takes too long to weaponize the stuff.  Though they could still easily steal and start using their enemies weapons...

Comment: @dsollen How about the Human Empire did not know of the minerals on Agoria until *after* troops started dying on great big hills of the stuff? Meanwhile, the slaves are present, *Doing! Their! Duty! To! The! Empire!* I'm certain that the tippy toe top secret after-action-reports and powerpointless decks could all be reduced to a single word: "Oops". I seem to remember in the Dune books, Harkonnen troops had explosives surgically implanted (heart plugs in the 1984 movie) so that they could give one last explosion/hurrah with their body when they died, quit, or were fired/dismissed.

Answer (score 3):

### Expense

As you mentioned, futuristic Space<sup>TM</sup> weaponry is much more powerful than twentieth century weaponry. However, it requires complex molecular engineering, is prone to manufacturing defects, and (most importantly) requires unobtainium. It thus can't be fabricated *en masse* like more primitive weaponry. As a result, you end up with an economy of scale.

When you're only trying to supply a small (i.e., planetary) army, energy weapons are a good choice. The advantages of more powerful weaponry outweigh their increased cost. On a large scale, however, the opposite is true. While I wouldn't necessarily say that the Imperium has an overabundance of warm bodies, it certainly has several orders of magnitude more than the Algorians. At that scale, troops' weapons merely need to be *capable* of killing someone; they don't have to be very good at it. Because of this, the Imperium prefers to save money by equipping its troops with older (but easily mass-produced) weapons.

**But what about the spaceships?**

Unlike troops, they're a large investment anyway. Thus, the Imperium's paper pushers approved the extra expenditure to ensure that those large investments don't get blown up.

Answer (score 2):

Humanity had an encounter with a runaway virus type AI.  Any time networks get complex enough, a bit of the AI code is triggered from somewhere (e.g. in a cute kitten image).  Since the AI code is virus like and holographic, you just have to stumble on a bit of it to start up one or more AIs.

Advanced energy generation/use damage the universe and eventually, 1%s the population.  This phenomena, after a few incidents, while not remembered, are embedded in the cultural conciseness. Much like how transwarp was damaging spacetime in ST:TNG.

Comment: While I like this, the "advanced energy use damages the universe" bit is a bit too extreme for my psuedoscientific world. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 1):

/humanity once had an empire sprawling hundreds of thousands of stars. Then it collapsed./

**Some things remain.**

[image: max from the Black Hole]

[source](https://www.giantfreakinrobot.com/ent/the-black-hole.html)

These ancient artifacts orbit Agoria.  They do not allow certain things to be brought into the system.  They do not publish this list of things.    Sometimes they give an entering ship notice that they are carrying proscribed items and give the ship time to turn around.  Sometimes they do not give notice.  Your would-be conquerors found out about these things the hard way and then found out how tough they were the very hard way.

Easier to work around them.  Show up with test batches of weapons.  Figure out what can get past.  Bring more of that stuff to use for your war making.  The stuff that is allowed past is the stuff you use.

The presence of these ancient things could be fun.  They are watching for prohibited weapons from space.  They are also watching the surface in case someone puts together a prohibited weapon from parts.

Comment: Very interesting. Perhaps the system is guarded *because* of the presence of monopoles  :D